# How can I extract written number in a answer sheet(image)

Tags: c#, vb.net

I tried tesseract but it only works on pure text document, can anyone suggest me what to do?

[image]
Here is my code for vb.net

```
Dim pic = New Bitmap(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
 Dim ocr = New TesseractEngine("./dataset", "eng", EngineMode.TesseractAndCube)
 Dim page = ocr.Process(pic)
 TextBox1.Text = page.GetText
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You do not seem to be asking any question outside your header, and your question body does not seem to contain an description of your problem, the error your are experiencing and the desired ouput. Please read [How do i ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your post to fit the format of SO.

Comment: sorry i'm new here, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your answer sheet is well structured. I would focus on extracting a sub-image for each answer, and then running Tesseract in single character mode on that image.
I'm not sure how you get single character mode in whatever Tesseract wrapper you're using, but via command line it's the parameter: `--psm 10`.

To extract each image, I would use OpenCV (try [Emgu](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) for .NET). You may need to first apply a perspective wrap in order to get the image square. You can then use a simple sliding window to get each sub image.

I'm not sure how this will perform in cases where an answer has been crossed out.